# Obtain the size of an integer at compile-time in Cython

Tags: cython

Is it possible, and if yes how, to determine the size, in bits, of the integer data types in Cython?

I'm trying to do something like this, to obtain the integers sizes:

```
cdef WORD_BITS = 0
IF sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8:
    WORD_BITS = 64
    DEF VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT = 6
ELSE:
    WORD_BITS = 32
    DEF VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT = 5

ctypedef unsigned long long word_t

cdef int vector_length(size_t bit_size):

    cdef size_t size = bit_size >> VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT
    if size << VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT < bit_size:
        size += 1
    return size

cdef class BitVector(object):

    cdef size_t length
    cdef size_t array_size
    cdef word_t *array

    def __cinit__(self, size_t size):
        self.length = size
        self.array_size = vector_length(size)
        self.array = <word_t *>calloc(self.array_size, sizeof(word_t))

    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(self.array)
```

I need to handle both the single bits of the elements of the array and the elements themselves, and thus I have to know how many bits they contain(to compute the proper masks/shifts). Trying to compile code like the above yields:

```
$python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling bitvector.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing bitvector.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport cython


# check whether we are running on a 64 or 32 bit architecture.
cdef WORD_BITS = 0
IF sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8:
  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

bitvector.pyx:7:3: Invalid compile-time expression

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize('bitvector.pyx')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 673, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 737, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: bitvector.pyx
```

Is there a working alternative?

I know that there is a `stdint.h` header that should define the integer types, but I cannot think of a way to use it since:

- I don't know how to check if a type is *not* defined(e.g. how do you write `IF uint64_t is not defined:` in cython?).
- Cython's documentation states that only things defined by `DEF` and the compiler can be checked in `IF`s, thus I doubt that I would be able to use `stdint.h` anyway.

---

It seems like this is not feasible in Cython since the check I want to make can only be performed when compiling from C to machine code, and not from cython to C.

Now I wonder: is it possible to write a cython extension in such a way that this kind of check is added in the C source code?

I mean, can I somehow write:

```
cdef WORD_BITS = 0
IF sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8:
    WORD_BITS = 64
    DEF VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT = 6
ELSE:
    WORD_BITS = 32
    DEF VECTOR_LENGTH_SHIFT_AMOUNT = 5

ctypedef unsigned long long word_t
```

In such a way that this `IF` "isn't processed" by Cython, but it is passed through and in the final C file there is the equivalent code?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Did you have any luck?

Comment: @PierreBdR Unfortunately no. I settled on always using a 32 bit data type, even though it's suboptimal in 64 bit machines. If you'd like an answer you could consider adding a bounty to this question (feel free to edit it, if you think it could be improved).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the preprocessor to define the size and shift values I would change your `vector_length` function slightly so that it can use `sizeof` directly. Cython will translate the `sizeof` operator correctly and the compiler will substitute the actual size of the type at *compile-time*. See this section from the glibc documentation for more information on using `sizeof` and `CHAR_BIT` to obtain the correct vector size: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport calloc, free
from libc.limits cimport CHAR_BIT

ctypedef unsigned long long word_t

cdef size_t vector_length(size_t bit_size):
    cdef size_t bits_per_word = CHAR_BIT*sizeof(word_t)
    return (bit_size + bits_per_word - 1) / bits_per_word

cdef class BitVector(object):
    cdef size_t length
    cdef size_t array_size
    cdef word_t *array

    def __cinit__(self, size_t size):
        self.length = size
        self.array_size = vector_length(size)
        self.array = <word_t *>calloc(self.array_size, sizeof(word_t))

    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(self.array)
```

It is also worth noting that `unsigned long long` is at least 64-bits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). Your code seems to assume that it can be *either* 64 or 32-bits but in a standards-compliant compiler it will only ever be 64-bits or more.